# Getting an error in entering time when default value for time is given in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I made the below Django form.

```
class SearchTimeSlotsForm(forms.Form):
    available_from = forms.TimeField(widget=TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'unbold-form'}), initial=time(0))
    available_till = forms.TimeField(widget=TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'unbold-form'}), initial=time(23,59,59))
```

As you can see that I have given default value to the form but when entering a value, I am getting an error 'Please select a valid value'.

Here is the screen shot of the error.

[image: Error screenshot]

Please note the user can enter any time, it has got nothing to do with the default value or its format so the above error should not come.

Can someone tell me why it is coming?

Link to GitHub repo [GitHub repo](https://github.com/AnshulGupta22/room_slot_booking/blob/main/hotel/forms.py)

Comment: what version of django you are using ?

Comment: @monim Django version 4.1

Comment: Can you also share your Html form which is rendering this? You are using the looping syntax?

Comment: @SunderamDubey I am using {{ form.as_p }} to render it in HTML.

Comment: @AnshulGupta I'd check your GitHub repo anyway.

Comment: @SunderamDubey So, did you got what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @AnshulGupta Sorry, I forgot to check, I'd check today.